# SQL database between multiple PCs using local connection Slower

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I make a program that uses an SQL SERVER database with VB.Net code , i use Linq to Sql to communicate to the SQL database , using 3 pc in a local area, the first one is the SERVER the two PC are the CLIENT, my problem is : when I execute the application on the SERVER it work like magic it's take only 2 or 5 second to fetch data from database, but, when I try to execute the application on the Client PC, it takes more than 20sec.

I already made an Index into the Table that I use it the most of the time, but the same problem.

this is the code that takes to much Time :

```
  Dim  data as new List(of Personne)
  data = (From c In bd.Personne Where c.originale = "yes" Order By c.num Descending Select c).ToList
```

I put this code into a BackgroundWorker put nothing is change.

Comment: any one please , juste an idea if you have it PLEAASE

Comment: Question is too general. Direct memory access used when you run program from server is hundreds times faster than network connection. You need to change your appproach and read data by portions

Comment: My guess is that you are reading the entire table to local and the table is big.  But we really need to know more, what are the indexes how is the table defined, how many rows... etc etc.

Comment: Even 2 to 5 seconds is much slower than it should be.

Comment: the Table that I use containes more than 5000 rows , for the indexes is used on the Colums that i use like First and Secande Name , City , on total is 21 index on the same Table because the Table has 50 colums , when I fetch the Hol Table is to make same Calculate like Chart

Comment: there is the problem -- 50 columns.  problem solved.

Comment: so what i should do ?

Comment: i must juste select the columns that i have to use, is that correct ?

Comment: To be clear:  Because the table rows are so big, just moving all the data you are not going to use is causing slowness as a bunch of junk moves over the network.  You want to be moving small things -- like IDs and not lots of data like 50 columns.  Only when you need the data do you query the DB for that detail.  This is why in relational DBs the additional data is often stored in a **related** table.

Comment: Ok Hogan thanks for the answer , i will make a test and i give you the feed-back :)

Comment: thanks a lot Hogan for your advice it work sooooo Faster , thanks again ^^

Answer (score 0):

If the database is on a remote server and you have round trip calls to SQL then its the extra time to transfer data over the network.  Two solutions: Re-write SQL query to stored procedure so all processing occurs on server or create web service on server to make call for data.